# Drag and drop overlapping points

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a graph plotted with a multitude of lines, a rather big figure overlapping the lines and ontop of that is a point that is capable of being drag and dropped all over the plot by the user.

The problem I'm facing currently is that as soon as the user drags and drops the point straight ontop of a line or a point of the figure, the user is unable to drag and drop the point away. I have set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq194ack/) with my current setup.

---

JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(function() {  
    var startPoint = [[7.00, 0]];

    var line10 = HHIsoPleth(7.00, 7.80, 10);
    var line120 = HHIsoPleth(7.00, 7.80, 120);

    var options = {
        series: {                       
            points: { 
                editMode: "none",
                show: true,
                radius: 0,
                symbol: "circle",
                fill: true,
                hoverable: false,
            },
            lines: {
                editMode: "none",
                editable: false,
                hoverable: false,
                clickable: false
            }
        },
        yaxes: [ { 
            position: "left", 
            min: 0, max: 60, 
            tickSize: 4, 
        } ],
        xaxes: [ { 
            position: "bottom", 
            min: 7.00, max: 7.80, 
        } ],
        grid: {
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            editable: true,
            hoverable: true, 
            clickable: false,
        },
        legend: {
            position: "nw"
        },              
    };      

    var data = [                
        { data: line10, label: "PCO2", lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1 }, points: { show: false }, editable: false, clickable: false, hoverable: false, color: "#FF0000" },
        { data: line120, lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1 }, points: { show: false }, editable: false, clickable: false, hoverable: false, color: "#FF0000" }, 

        { data: startPoint, label: "Bloedzuur gehalte", lines: { show: true }, points: { show: true, radius: 3 }, editable: true, editMode: 'xy', color: '#00FF00' },
    ];

    var plot = $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), data, options);

    // Drag and drop
    $("#flot-placeholder").bind("datadrop", function(event, pos, item) {        
        var PCO2 = getPCO2(pos.x1.toFixed(2), pos.y1.toFixed(2));
        var pH = getPH(pos.y1.toFixed(2), PCO2);
        var HCOmm = getHCO3(pH, PCO2);

        updatePoint(pH, HCOmm);
    });

    // Generate red lines / isopleths
    function HHIsoPleth(minPH, maxPH, PCO2){
        var isoPleth = [];
        for (var i = minPH; i < maxPH; i+=0.01){
            HCOmm = (0.03 * PCO2 * Math.pow(10,i-6.1));
            isoPleth.push([i,HCOmm]);
        }
        return isoPleth;
    }

    function getHCO3(ph, pco2) {
        return 0.03 * pco2 * Math.pow(10, ph - 6.1);
    }

    function getPH(hco3, pco2) {
        return 6.1 + Math.log10(hco3 / (0.03 * pco2));
    }

    function getPCO2(ph, hco3) {
        return (hco3 / 0.03) * Math.pow(10, 6.1 - ph);
    }

    //Reset point
    $("#davenportReset").click(function() {
        updatePoint(7.00, 0);
    });

    function updatePoint(x, y) {
        data[16].data[0] = [x, y];
        $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), data, options);
    }

    // Debug purpose, get the index of the point that is clicked
    $("#placeholder").bind("plotdown", function(event,pos,item){
        $("#log").append("\nplotdown(" + item.seriesIndex + ")"); 
    });
});
```

Additional libraries: [Flot.js](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js), [JUMFlot](http://jumjum123.github.io/JUMFlot/javascripts/JUMFlot.min.js)

HTML:

```
    <input class="davenportInput" id="davenportReset" type="button" value="Reset Point" />
<div id="flot-placeholder" style="width:558px;height:511px"></div>
    eventlog<textarea id="log" rows="15" cols="28"></textarea>
```

---

In the provided fiddle you'll see that you can drag and drop the green point all around the plot. But once you drop it ontop any of the red lines it is no longer possible to drag and drop the green point somewhere else. In the textarea you'll see that when you click the green point, `plotdown(16)` will be shown in the textarea. But will show `plotdown(0-15)` when it is clicked when the point is over any of the red/yellow lines.

**Would it be possible to get the 16th data serie(the drag and drop point) when it's overlapping any of the red lines?**

---

Using (once again) Mark's answer I solved it. One condition I had though was that I had to keep the green point above all other lines.

This is what I did:

```
    var startPoint = [[7.00, 0]];
    var invisPoint = [[7.00, 0]];

    var line10 = HHIsoPleth(7.00, 7.80, 10);
    var line120 = HHIsoPleth(7.00, 7.80, 120);
```

To create a invisible placeholder point.

I than added it to the data object

```
    var data = [

    { data: invisPoint , lines: { show: false }, points: { show: false, radius: 3 }, editable: true, editMode: 'xy', color: '#00FF00' },

    { data: line10, label: "PCO2", lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1 }, points: { show: false }, editable: false, clickable: false, hoverable: false, color: "#FF0000" },
    { data: line120, lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1 }, points: { show: false }, editable: false, clickable: false, hoverable: false, color: "#FF0000" }, 

    { data: startPoint, label: "Bloedzuur gehalte", lines: { show: true }, points: { show: true, radius: 3 }, editable: true, editMode: 'xy', color: '#00FF00' },
];
```

And updated the updatePoint function

```
        function updatePoint(x, y) {
            var data = plot.getData();
            data[0].data[0] = [x, y]; // Invisible point
            data[17].data[0] = [x, y]; // Green point
            plot.setData(data);
            plot.draw();
        }
```

This way, the invisible point gets selected and dragged and dropped. I simply use those coordinates to position the green point aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, `flot` or `jumflot` in this case, when you mousedown is searching the points to see if one is near enough to your mouse cursor.  It searches the points in order and finds your line segment before the point.  So, simple fix, place your move-able point first:

```
var data = [    
            { data: startPoint, label: "Bloedzuur gehalte", lines: { show: true }, points: { show: true, radius: 3 }, editable: true, editMode: 'xy', color: '#00FF00' },
            { data: line10, label: "PCO2", lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1 }, points: { show: false }, editable: false, clickable: false, hoverable: false, color: "#FF0000" },
  ....
```

In addition, update your plot like this:

```
function updatePoint(x, y) {
    var data = plot.getData();
    data[0].data[0] = [x, y];
    plot.setData(data);
    plot.draw();
}
```

Calling `$.plot` over and over again is expensive and will probably leak memory (it used to at least - not sure if it was every fixed).

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq194ack/1/).

Comment: Solved it, thanks! I tried it at one point to place it first, but completely forgot about it.